# In Commerce how can I have a customer update custom fields on an order after the order is completed?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm using Commerce, and Orders can have a custom field on them. I need customers to be able to update that field from a front end form. I can't use the built in contoller for Orders because that requires Admin users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new plugin with a new controller class that enables this.

e.g.,

plugins/myplugin/MyPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Craft;
class MyPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    ... the usual stuff from https://pluginfactory.io/ etc ...
}
?>
```

plugins/myplugin/controllers/My_OrdersController.php

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class My_OrdersController extends BaseController
{

    public function actionUpdateOrder()
    {
        // basic security precautions
            $this->requirePostRequest();

        // get the fields
            $orderNumber = craft()->request->getPost('orderNumber');
            $customField = craft()->request->getPost('customField');
            $order       = craft()->commerce_orders->getOrderByNumber($orderNumber);

        // do the stuff
            if ($order &&
                $order->customer->userId == craft()->userSession->getUser()->id &&
                $customField != '')
            {
                    $order->setContentFromPost(['customField'=>$customField]);

                    // Lets also change the Order Status
                        $order->orderStatusId = 3; // this line changes the Status if wanted. Use the ID of the custom status.
                        $order->message = "Order status changed to 'To be cancelled' by customer";

                    craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($order);
            }
    }
}
```

Front end form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myplugin/orders/updateOrder">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="shop/customer/order?number={{ number }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderNumber" value="{{ number }}"> 

    <label>
        <span>Custo Field</span>
        <input type="text"
                name="customField"
                value="{{ order.customField }}"
        />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="button warning" value="Confirm"/>
</form>
```